# R boot: Function for bootstrapping a glm cannot find index argument

Tags: r, glm

I encounter a problem when trying to bootstrap a glm. It is quite puzzling to me as similar procedures have worked in the past.

Using the following function to fit my glm and extract the relevant statistics:

```
glm_fun <- function(data, ix) {
  fit <- glm(anyturn ~ hk + einst + alt + age, data=data[ix, ], family=binomial(link="logit"),
             subset = ku_g=="ok")
  Eff <- coef(fit)
  OR <- exp(coef(fit))
  Rsq <- rsq::rsq(fit, type="n")
  c(Eff, OR, Rsq)
}
```

Then I call the bootsrap algorithm like so:

```
bs_out <- boot::boot(data=mydata, statistic=glm_fun, R=1000, stype="i")
```

And surprisingly I get the following error message: `Fehler in is.data.frame(data) : Objekt 'ix' nicht gefunden` (i.e. Error in is.data.frame(data): Object 'ix' not found`)

The error also appears when I don't even use the `boot`-function but just try my `glm_fun`-function:
`glm_fun(data=mydata, ix=rep(TRUE, nrow(mydata)) )`

All the variables in the formula plus the one used for subsetting are in my data frame and there is no variable called `ix` in it.

Any ideas as to what I did wrong are very appreciated!

---

**Edit:** making it reproducible (hopefully)

So I just generated some random data with a similar structure. I still get the error message (see comment in code). The following is *all code* executed after restarting R:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)
mydata <- list(Apred = rnorm(200),
               Bpred = rnorm(200),
               Cpred = rnorm(200)
               ) %>% as.data.frame()
mydata$DV <- with(mydata, rnorm(200) + Apred*0.2 + Bpred*0.1 + Cpred*0.3) %>% cut(c(-5,0,5), labels=c("lo", "hi"))

glm(DV ~ Apred + Bpred + Cpred, data=mydata, family=binomial("logit")) %>% summary()
#This gives a reasonable output

glm_fun <- function(data, ix) {
  fit <- glm(DV ~ Apred + Bpred + Cpred, data=data[ix, ], family=binomial(link="logit") )
  Eff <- coef(fit)
  OR <- exp(coef(fit))
  Rsq <- rsq::rsq(fit, type="n")
  c(Eff, OR, Rsq)
}

bs_out <- boot::boot(mydata, statistic=glm_fun, R=500) #but this gives an error (Object 'ix' not found)

glm_fun(mydata, ix=rep(TRUE, nrow(mydata))) #...and so does this.
```

In case it's relevant: I am running R 4.0.0 on Windows 10 (x64) through RStudio

Comment: is it possible that the `subset` argument is causing trouble?

Comment: That should work. Try restarting r without loading any previous workspace, and running again. If pronblem persists we likely need to see some data to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried two things: 1. removed the `subset` argument: problem persists. 2. Restarted R to get rid of any loaded packages: problem persists. I am going to try and provide some example data to make it reproducible.

Comment: thanks for the update. A quick run seems to show the issue is with `rsq::rsq`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. I falsely assumed that it must be something about the glm call. Removing `rsq` gets the bootstrap running and giving reasonable results.

Comment: it seems to be a scoping issue with the `update` function in `rsq:::rsq.n`. Short of adding the lines of `rsq.n` to your boot function, I am not sure how to firce it too be recognised. Im sure @BenBolker will have some suggestions.

Comment: `rsq.n` uses `update`, which tries to evaluate in the parent frame, which is `rsq`.  It might indeed help to call `rsq.n` directly ...

Comment: Using `rsq.n` instead of `rsq` did not solve the problem but including the code from within the `rsq.n` function made it work.